# jQuery every fourth element unless last

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a 'caption' element after every fourth element, which I have working using this, and it works great.

```
$('.each-work:nth-of-type(4n)').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>');
});
```

The only is the number of elements isn't divisible by four, and it's a CMS adding the elements so the number of elements could grow/shrink regularly. How do I edit this function to include the remaining elements outside the `4n`?

As an example, currently it looks like this:

```
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
```

Whereas I'd ideally like:

```
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work"></div>
<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>
```

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as well as selecting every 4th child, select the last child too:

```
$('.each-work:nth-of-type(4n), .each-work:last-of-type').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xAC7/1/)

Comment: if the last child would be divisible by 4 then the appended element would be duplicate.

Comment: I would highly recommend being consistent with the use of either `:nth-of-type(4n)` and `:last-of-type`, or `:nth-child(4n)` and `:last-child`, depending on the original structure.

Comment: or you can simply use `$('.each-work:nth-of-type(4n), .each-work:last-of-type').after('<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>');`

[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/7xAC7/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function addNewDiv() {
    $(this).after('<div class="each-work each-works-caption"><ul></ul></div>');
}

$('.each-work')
    .filter(':nth-of-type(4n)')
        .each(addNewDiv)
        .end()
    .last()
        .each(addNewDiv);
```